# Outputting ES6 (*.es.js) and ES5 (*.js) simultaneously with Typescript

Tags: typescript

I've noticed a common trend with several libraries lately that they output both an `index.es.js` for ESModule based imports and a `index.js` for backwards compatibility.

Is it possible to have Typescript export both of these in one pass? Or would this require two passes and if so what is the cleanest command; For example `tsc --target="ES6" outFile="index.es.js" && tsc --target="ES5" outFile="index.js"`.

Comment: This will require two tsc calls, as these are separate output options and you can only specify one.

Comment: Do you know what the most efficient tsconfig + cli command line inputs would be to get the correct output? Feel free to post an answer and I'll accept it :-)

Comment: I would say what you have in your op is fine.